# Getting Access key and Access token key from Magento

Tags: java, magento, oauth, scribe

Retrieving Access token and Access token secret key from Magento using Scribe-1.3.1.jar in java , for third party integration i am able to get the Access key but after entering the code it is giving following error.

**Error is:**

1.0
Magento's OAuth Workflow

Fetching the Request Token...
obtaining request token from 
setting oauth_callback to oob
generating signature...
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.22%2Fmagento%2Foauth%2Finitiate&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3D900bf8e5bd9634637c6a037d8d051209%26oauth_nonce%3D2723540211%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1406010098%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: gMqc93kp2yX91xuwViBNa/ZH5rI=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> gMqc93kp2yX91xuwViBNa/ZH5rI= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 2723540211 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> 900bf8e5bd9634637c6a037d8d051209 , oauth_timestamp -> 1406010098 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 200
response body: oauth_token=cb72f3a6fa004e4f0cf10d3e7584f4fb&oauth_token_secret=0dbea97335e036747965a1268f51590b&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
Got the Request Token!

Fetching the Authorization URL...
Got the Authorization URL!
Now go and authorize Main here:
http://www.samplewebsite.com/magento/ROOT/admin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=cb72f3a6fa004e4f0cf10d3e7584f4fb
And paste the authorization code here

> > 0dbea97335e036747965a1268f51590b

Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...
obtaining access token from http://www.samplewebsite.com/magento/oauth/token
setting token to: Token[cb72f3a6fa004e4f0cf10d3e7584f4fb , 0dbea97335e036747965a1268f51590b] and verifier to: org.scribe.model.Verifier@7f4a6c40
generating signature...
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.22%2Fmagento%2Foauth%2Ftoken&oauth_consumer_key%3D900bf8e5bd9634637c6a037d8d051209%26oauth_nonce%3D1510697252%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1406010111%26oauth_token%3Dcb72f3a6fa004e4f0cf10d3e7584f4fb%26oauth_verifier%3D0dbea97335e036747965a1268f51590b%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: +Fjjimu7RBDnD+Wj5SP1gfv1LKo=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> +Fjjimu7RBDnD+Wj5SP1gfv1LKo= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 1510697252 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> 900bf8e5bd9634637c6a037d8d051209 , oauth_token -> cb72f3a6fa004e4f0cf10d3e7584f4fb , oauth_verifier -> 0dbea97335e036747965a1268f51590b , oauth_timestamp -> 1406010111 }
using Http Header signature

**Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'oauth_problem=verifier_invalid'
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:82)
    at auth.main(auth.java:61)**

Can anybody please help me in this case......

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got same issue finally resolve this gotcha.
In controller you have to change authorize admin url '/admin/oAuth_authorize' to '/admin/oauth_authorize'.
Its a case sensitive.